# FFMpeg produces low quality target file with just 1 second length on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using FFMpeg locally on a Mac (actually using PHP-FFMpeg) and it's working perfectly. I'm running the same code on an Ubuntu server and whatever I try the output file is a tiny, low quality video with just 1 second length (the original is about 15 seconds).

I installed it on the server with

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

and then restarted the server. To test now I'm running

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 target.mp4
```

from the terminal and getting this output

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'source.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : iso5
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomiso5hlsf
    creation_time   : 2021-07-16T05:37:58.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:00.66, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 74037 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 83522 kb/s, 30.20 fps, 600 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-07-16T05:37:58.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 1774 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-07-16T05:37:58.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
File 'target.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x55db778748c0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x55db778748c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x55db778748c0] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x55db778748c0] 264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
frame=    8 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbOutput #0, mp4, to 'target.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : iso5
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomiso5hlsf
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 30.20 fps, 28k tbn, 30.20 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-07-16T05:37:58.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-07-16T05:37:58.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 aac
frame=   15 fps= 14 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=3 droframe=   18 fps= 11 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.46 bitrate=   0.8kbits/sframe=   18 fps=7.9 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.46 bitrate=   0.8kbits/sframe=   18 fps=6.4 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.46 bitrate=   0.8kbits/sframe=   19 fps=5.8 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.46 bitrate=   0.8kbits/sframe=   19 fps=5.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.46 bitrate=   0.8kbits/sframe=   20 fps=4.6 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.46 bitrate=   0.8kbits/s[aac @ 0x55db778a2f00] Queue input is backward in time
[mp4 @ 0x55db77876100] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 23552, current: 20480; changing to 23553. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x55db77876100] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 23553, current: 21504; changing to 23554. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x55db77876100] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 23554, current: 22528; changing to 23555. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x55db77876100] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 23555, current: 23552; changing to 23556. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
frame=   20 fps=3.3 q=-1.0 Lsize=      77kB time=00:00:00.56 bitrate=1122.7kbits/s dup=3 drop=3 speed=0.0936x    
video:69kB audio:6kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.688508%
[libx264 @ 0x55db778748c0] frame I:1     Avg QP:22.13  size: 14863
[libx264 @ 0x55db778748c0] frame P:5     Avg QP:25.37  size:  6279
[libx264 @ 0x55db778748c0] frame B:14    Avg QP:26.80  size:  1720
[libx264 @ 0x55db778748c0] consecutive B-frames:  5.0%  0.0% 15.0% 80.0%
[libx264 @ 0x55db778748c0] mb I  I16..4: 15.9% 65.9% 18.2%
[libx264 @ 0x55db778748c0] mb P  I16..4: 10.6% 11.7%  1.3%  P16..4: 52.4% 11.2%  5.5%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 7.4%
[libx264 @ 0x55db778748c0] mb B  I16..4:  1.0%  1.3%  0.4%  B16..8: 35.8%  3.0%  0.5%  direct: 2.4%  skip:55.6%  L0:41.2% L1:55.5% BI: 3.3%
[libx264 @ 0x55db778748c0] 8x8 transform intra:56.1% inter:82.3%
[libx264 @ 0x55db778748c0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 54.1% 75.0% 21.1% inter: 14.6% 25.2% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x55db778748c0] i16 v,h,dc,p:  9% 19%  3% 70%
[libx264 @ 0x55db778748c0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 19% 18% 24%  5%  6%  9%  6%  6%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x55db778748c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 30% 20% 16%  6%  7%  7%  6%  5%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x55db778748c0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 48% 25% 22%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x55db778748c0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:40.0% UV:40.0%
[libx264 @ 0x55db778748c0] ref P L0: 62.4% 17.4% 14.3%  5.7%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x55db778748c0] ref B L0: 87.6% 10.7%  1.7%
[libx264 @ 0x55db778748c0] ref B L1: 95.0%  5.0%
[libx264 @ 0x55db778748c0] kb/s:849.86
[aac @ 0x55db778a2f00] Qavg: 4594.708
```

Here's what the files look like

[image]

Any ideas what could be wrong?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: 1) 4.2 release branch is old. [Download a recent ffmpeg](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) (git version, not release) and try again. 2) Problem may be edit list. Try `ffmpeg -ignore_editlist true -i source.mp4 target.mp4` 3) If both suggestions fail to help then provide a link to `source.mp4` if possible.

Comment: Wonderful, perfect answer @llogan thank you! I followed the instruction at https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/05/install-ffmpeg-4-4-ppa-ubuntu-20-04-21-04/ in get the latest version and it's running perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

@llogan gave the perfect answer, see comments above. I ran this on the server to upgrade FFMpeg to the latest version and it's working correctly now

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/ffmpeg4
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/graphics
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:savoury1/multimedia
sudo apt full-upgrade
ffmpeg -version
```